# Elementary row operation (3x3) with all rows = 0 except row 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

i was working on elementary row operations and found this as result

$$
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    x & y & z \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$

does this count as a result of elementary row operations?

thank you

Comment: Any matrix can be the result of elementary row operations (for one thing, they're all reversible, so you can start with any matrix, apply a row operation, and then apply its inverse to arrive at the original matrix). Are you asking whether the given matrix is in row-reduced form? The answer is yes.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, i was just making sure whether the matrix above can be considered as a result of row operations

Comment: This is a perfectly well-formed mathematical question, but I do want to point out that it's like asking whether a number can be considered as a result of subtraction. They all can, so that's probably not exactly the question one means to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Let's recall what is the exact classification of elementary row operations: (Row Swap) Exchange of any two rows; (Scalar Multiplication) Multiplication of any row by a constant number; (Row Sum) Addition of a multiple of one row to another row. As mentioned in the comment section, using those $3$ possible operations (specifically Row Swap), it is easily derivable to prove that matrix $$
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    x & y & z \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$
could be indeed the resultant matrix after some finite number of row-elementary operations for some initial matrix.